# Is there a way to see token ranges for each node in cassandra which uses vnodes?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, nodetool

Is there a way to see token ranges for each node in cassandra which used vnodes? I dont want to see token for each node which you get by issuing nodetool ring. I just want to see the token ranger for each node which uses vnodes.

Answer (score 2):

The token ranges for a given node will be a function of a keyspace's topology.

Programmatically you can use the java-driver for this using [Cluster.getMetadata().getTokenRanges(keyspace, host)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/Metadata.html#getTokenRanges-java.lang.String-com.datastax.driver.core.Host-).  The following code example shows retrieving all token ranges by host for a keyspace:

```java
String keyspace = "mykeyspace";
for(Host host : cluster.getMetadata().getAllHosts()) {
    Set<TokenRange> hostRanges = cluster.getMetadata().getTokenRanges(keyspace, host);
}
```

Additionally you can get at this using JMX to a Cassandra node via `org.apache.cassandra.db:type=StorageService#getRangeToEndpointMap|getRangeToRpcaddressMap(String)`